# Make a sparse tensor based on the output of tf.nn.top_k

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I hope some one can help me on this.
I want to make a tensor from the highest values in dimension -1 of another tensor, with the same size while other values set to zero.

For example, given a tensor `X` of size `[2,3,4,5]`, assume we want to compute the 2 largest elements in the last channel :

```
vals, indices = tf.nn.top_k(X, k=2, sorted=False)
```

Obviously, shape of vals and indices are `[2,3,4,2]`.
Now, we want to make the tensor `Y`, with shape `[2,3,4,5]` while only 2 values in each channel with location of indices having values in vals and the rest set to zero. I think I should use tf.sparse_to_dense, but I do not know how exactly.

Second Question : What if the dimension `0` is the number of batches and it is dynamic, i.e., it is not given :

```
X.shape = (?,3,4,5)
```

Note : This is useful in making spatially sparse layers and sparse auto-encoders.

Thanks in advance.